# Ambiguous factory method matches found in bean 'container'

Tags: java, spring, spring-amqp

I want to implement multiple queue listeners in Spring amqp application. I tried this:

```
    @Bean
    public SimpleMessageListenerContainer container(ConnectionFactory cf, DatabaseTransactionListener listener) {
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(cf);
        container.setQueueNames(QUEUE_DATABASE_TRANSACTION);
        container.setMessageListener(new MessageListenerAdapter(listener, "databaseTransaction"));
        container.setMessageConverter(new SerializerMessageConverter());
        return container;
    }

    @Component
    class DatabaseTransactionListener {

        public TransactionsBean databaseTransaction(TransactionsBean ro) {
            TransactionsBean obj = new TransactionsBean();
            System.out.println("!!!! Performing TransactionsBean processing !!!!");
            obj.setTransaction_id(" ??? some_id: " + ro.getMerchant_id());
            return obj;
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleMessageListenerContainer container(ConnectionFactory cf, ApiAttemptListener listener) {
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(cf);
        container.setQueueNames(QUEUE_DATABASE_API_ATTEMPT);
        container.setMessageListener(new MessageListenerAdapter(listener, "apiattemptTransaction"));
        container.setMessageConverter(new SerializerMessageConverter());
        return container;
    }

    @Component
    class ApiAttemptListener {

        public ApiAttemptsBean apiattemptTransaction(ApiAttemptsBean ro) {
            ApiAttemptsBean obj = new ApiAttemptsBean();
            System.out.println("!!!! Performing ApiAttempts processing !!!!");
            obj.setMerchant_id(454545);
            return obj;
        }
    }
```

I get error during startup: `Error creating bean with name 'container' defined in org.database.context.ContextServer: Ambiguous factory method matches found in bean 'container'`

What is the proper way to implement multiple listeners in order to process multiple queues?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bean names and bean factory method names have to be unique; when using `@Bean`, the default bean name is the method name.

Give the bean factory methods unique names `container1()`, `container2()`.

Comment: Thanks! Surprisingly this worked till I upgraded spring boot version from 2.0.4 to 2.3.0.RELEASE

Comment: Newer Boots disable bean overriding by default because it can cause unexpected side-effeects.